# Connect Postgres RDS instance from local Database client

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I have a Postgres RDS instance running in a private Subnet. It is accessible through a EC2 as a bastion host, as EC2 instance is configured in a public subnet in the same VPC as the private subnet. I can `ssh` to the RDS instance through the jump server.
Is there a way I can DBeaver client to the RDS instance? Do I need to configure a VPN connection for that? What are the different options here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stablish a connection to the DB through the jump server using SSH Tunnel:

1. Create new connection
   [image]
2. Configure SSH settings using the fields of the bastion host (use password or private key)
   [image]
3. Specify PostgreSQL user/password/endpoint and test the connection
   [image]